# Tailwind classes not working with html file

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am getting a different font output because of tailwindcss but the classes aren't showing any output.

The files:

**package.json**

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build style.css -o css/style.css"
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="font-sans">Welcome to my tailwind course</h1>
      <h2 class="font-serif">Created by Varun Prasannan</h2>
      <p class="font-mono">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, dignissimos numquam temporibus quisquam optio suscipit neque iure nam ab architecto quaerat similique vero, a aperiam impedit dolores. Autem, iure expedita.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, different font classes are applied such as

```
class="font-sans"
class="font-serif"
class="font-mono"
```

but the output is the same tailwindcss default font.

I have a feeling that the paths to some files(that I don't know of) have to be updated in the **tailwind.config.js** file, but i don't exactly know the path format.

Comment: Any reason your `content` array is empty in your [config file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure with this problem, but I recommend you to follow the installation instructions from Tailwind, which I will put it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Besides I spotted the content field in your tailwind config file is empty, in which you should have specified the path to all of your template files. Here is an example, what this does is pointing to all html and JS file in your src folder. Hope this might help

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I also faced similar issues when trying to setup a project using Vite. Postcss was not  installed. The official Tailwind installation instructions helped. In my case, postcss config file was not generated and hence none of the tailwindcss files were getting recognized.

Answer (score 2):

According to Tailwind docs:

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}'
  ],
  // ...
}
```

1. Use `*` to match anything except slashes and hidden files
2. Use `**` to match zero or more directories
3. Use comma-separate values between `{}` to match against a list of options

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Add html file path to tailwind.config.js file "content" tab. Here my HTML file is in public folder and styles.css in src folder. And important step is run this command immediately.

npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./public/styles.css

then only tailwind classes are reflecting on live-server

```
module.exports = {
    content: ["./public/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```